# のに (noni) versus けど (kedo) to mean “but, although" etc

Tags: grammar, words

So guys I searched about this difference and didn't find a conclusive answer.

What is the difference or is there any difference at all like this:

> この部屋はいつもきれいな**のに**今日はちらかっている。

Although this room is always clean, today it is a "mess".

> この部屋はいつもきれい**だけど**今日はちらかっている。

This room is always clean but today it is a "mess".

For me it's like のに focuses on the first part of the sentence:

> この部屋はいつもきれい

and けど focuses on the second part:

> 今日はちらかっている

Am I right?

のに can be used like けど and vice versa?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

のに introduces some disappointment.
The room's owner would probably say the first sentence.

The second sentence is just an observation.

The のに includes a soft 'Why isn't it clean as always ?'

Answer (score 3):

Both are almost identical actually, but I feel a slight sensation of regret from the のに version.

So, you may be right. When a person says この部屋はいつもきれいな**のに**, s/he is perhaps picturing the tidy room it used to be in his/her mind, from which a tinge of disappointment rises at the sight of the mess of actual room.

On the other hand, the けど version seems to be pretty neutral and objective, with no sensation.